# Need to create subquery in Access 2016 that gives a distinct count

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

So I am trying to create a query that will return the total weight of food taken out of our food cupboard by students (I work at a university food cupboard) and I am able to get it to give me all of the totals I need except for a count of distinct students that come in. Basically, I need it to give me the number of different students that come in instead of the number of transactions it's giving me right now. Anyone out there know how to fix it? Current code is below:

`Student_ID` is the field that I need the subquery on if I'm correct...

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW 
    Format$([Transaction Table].[Date],'mmmm yyyy') AS [Month], 
    Sum([Transaction Table].Weight) AS [Total Weight], 
    Count(*) AS [Total Transaction], 
    Count([Transaction Table].Student_ID) AS [Unique Customers]
FROM [Transaction Table]
GROUP BY 
    Format$([Transaction Table].[Date],'mmmm yyyy'), 
    Year([Transaction Table].[Date])*12+DatePart('m',[Transaction Table].[Date])-1;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be done without some type of join, since you need both distinct transactions *and* distinct students.  That's asking for a subset within a subset.  What we used to do was create a "key" field in the main query (i.e. SELECT 1 as Key) and then do the same thing in another query and just join the two by the Key field since they're identical.  You might need to do something like that here, although it looks like you're grouping by Month/Year so you can probably use that instead of Key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! My problem was that I was trying to link all of the month fields together. What I needed to do was create two queries to first count the distinctive customers by month, another to get the number of transactions and the weight per month, and then write a final query to merge all the fields I needed together. Fixed code is below:

Transaction count query:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW 
    Format$([Transaction Table].[Date],'mm/yyyy') AS [Month],
    Sum([Transaction Table].Weight) AS [Total Weight], 
    Count(*) AS [Total Transactions]
FROM [Transaction Table]
GROUP BY 
    Format$([Transaction Table].[Date],'mm/yyyy'), 
    Year([Transaction Table].[Date])*12+DatePart('m',[Transaction Table].[Date])-1;
```

Unique Customer count query:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW 
    [Month], 
    Count(ID) AS [Unique Customers]
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
        [Student_ID] AS ID, 
        Format$([Date],'mm/yyyy') AS [Month] 
    FROM [Transaction Table])  AS [%$##@_Alias]
GROUP BY 
    [Month], 
    Year([Month])*12+DatePart('m',[Month])-1;
```

Final query to combine results of first two:

```
SELECT 
    [Transaction Montly Query].Month, 
    [Transaction Montly Query].[Total Weight], 
    [Transaction Montly Query].[Total Transactions], 
    Format$(([Total Weight]/[Total Transactions]),'#.00') AS [Weight per Transaction], 
    [Unique Customer Query].[Unique Customers], 
    Format$(([Total Weight]/[Unique Customers]),'#.00') AS [Weight per Costomer], 
    Format$(([Total Transactions]/[Unique Customers]),'#.00') AS [Transactions per Customer]
FROM [Transaction Montly Query] 
    RIGHT JOIN [Unique Customer Query] 
        ON [Transaction Montly Query].Month = [Unique Customer Query].Month
GROUP BY 
    [Transaction Montly Query].Month, 
    [Transaction Montly Query].[Total Weight], 
    [Transaction Montly Query].[Total Transactions], 
    [Unique Customer Query].[Unique Customers]
ORDER BY [Transaction Montly Query].Month;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the number of distinct students per date, you can use the following:

```
SELECT Count(Student_ID) As StudentCount, ShortDate
FROM 
   (SELECT Student_ID, Format$([Date], "Short Date") As ShortDate
    FROM [Transaction Table] 
    GROUP BY Student_ID, Format$([Date], "Short Date"))
GROUP BY ShortDate
```

Then you can join it on the date.

Doing it in one statement, however, will be difficult, since Access doesn't like nested subqueries.

Comment: The only issue with that is I need it to give me all the information it currently is, but I also need it to give me a distinct count on the `Student_ID` field. Everything else is giving me the numbers I need. My biggest problem at this point, I think, is that I have no clue how Access runs subqueries...

Comment: You can just use this in a separate query, and then join the query with yours on the date.

Comment: I'm sorry for sounding like a dolt, but how does one do that haha? I have never done any type of join before.

Comment: Let's say you save my query and call it QueryA. Then you can use the following code: 
`SELECT DISTINCTROW 
    Format$([Date],'mmmm yyyy') AS [Month], 
    Sum([Transaction Table].Weight) AS [Total Weight], 
    Count(*) AS [Total Transaction], 
    Count([Transaction Table].Student_ID) AS [Unique Customers], StudentCount
FROM [Transaction Table]
INNER JOIN QueryA ON Format$([Date], "Short Date") = ShortDate
GROUP BY 
    Format$([Transaction Table].[Date],'mmmm yyyy'), 
    Year([Transaction Table].[Date])*12+DatePart('m',[Transaction Table].[Date])-1, Studentcount;`